# Submit form without attached file

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I want to create JSF form with attached file. But also to give a option form the users to submit the for without attach file. I don't want this to be mandatory.

```
<h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">                               
    <div class="string">
        <label class="name">                                       
            <h:inputText id="name" value="#{contacts.name}" pt:placeholder="Name*:"/>
        </label>
    </div>
    <label class="message">                                    
        <h:inputTextarea value="#{contacts.comment}" pt:placeholder="Comment*:"/>
    </label>
    <h:inputFile id="fileToUpload" value="#{contacts.file}" required="true" requiredMessage="No file selected ..."/>
    <h:commandButton value="Upload" action="#{contacts.upload()}">
        <f:ajax execute="fileToUpload" />
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:message showDetail="false" showSummary="true" for="fileToUpload" style="color:red"/>
    <div class="btns">
        <h:commandLink id="submitlink" class="link" value="submit" action="#{contacts.sendEmail}" >
            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form" onevent="handleDisableButton" resetValues="true"/>
        </h:commandLink>
    </div>
    <h:outputText id="output" value="#{contacts.result}" />
</h:form>
```

Is there a way to implement this because now if I try to submit the form I always get message `No file selected ...`?
Also when I attach a file using the button upload button no message appears for successful file upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your `inputFile` as **required**. That is why you have to upload first always.

Also, if you are not seeing any message it's because you are not rendering again your `h:message`. Try using this in your managed bean:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds()
.add("idMessage");
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
<h:inputFile id="fileToUpload" value="#{contacts.file}" required="true" requiredMessage="No file selected ..."/>
```

to

```
<h:inputFile id="fileToUpload" value="#{contacts.file}" />
```